# Make Jenkins behave as compile-only tool and then handle all resulting artifacts on primary Jenkins interface

Tags: windows, ant, continuous-integration, jenkins

It might be the case here some of things I have in my mind and in this subject has already been discussed here, but I really would be very thankfull to have step-by-step answer on achieving the following efect on Jenkins CI, First of all - here is tools I can operate with:

- Two Jenkins CI servers - Jenkins A and Jenkins B ;
- Jenkins B cannot serve as data storage for builds, therefore the artifacts, test, etc. should be saved on Jenkins A :( ;
- Apache Ant ( latest ) and NAnt ( latest ) .

The goal is to achieve the following: Ability to start build on Jenkins A, make source code and build on Jenkins B, but archive and show the artifacts again on Jenkins A.

As much I have googled, I found there is term widely used - "distributed build" ... is it the case here, too?

Currently using latest Jenkis CI version available on both machines ( Jenkins A and Jenkins B ).

What job config I need to use to be able to do such multi-Jenkins setup under my company domain?

Answer (score 3):

You do not want to have a full Jenkins install on both machine.

What is sounds like to me is you should be installing Jenkins on machine A, and set up machine B as a slave node to that Jenkins installation. The Jenkins UI makes this very intuitive, but if you need details they are available here:

- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines
- https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds

Once you've done that, you will need to explicitly configure your job so that it:

1. Archives whatever artifacts you need archived (you probably have this done already).
2. Builds only on the machine B slave node by entering the node name in "Restrict where this job can be built."

Comment: And what to do with artifacts on limited capacity slave machine? It requiers to copy and delete artifacts anyway ...

Comment: Artifacts are archived on the master... Exactly as you asked for